# Can different size feet be a cause of knee pain?

Tags: cleat

Left foot is close to a full size bigger than right.  I have always had some left knee pain since going clipless.  Have always went with the shoe size for the larger foot.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @daryl!

Comment: I would wager that you have some slight malformation of one leg that is causing the knee pain.  But the point made in the answers below about having the cleats properly (and identically) positioned relative to the foot (not the shoe) is something to check out.  Remember, with clips your toes were jammed toward the front, but with clipless your feet tend to be pulled to the rear of the shoes.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the pain?  Where in the knee? (e.g., outside below the knee joint.) When does it show up? (e.g., whenever riding up hills, after x hours of riding easy, etc.) How repeatable it is? (e.g., always occurs, occurs approximately every 5th ride, etc.)

Comment: When it happened to me it was from carrying a bike U-lock on the side of the bike which forced one knee to be slightly (asymmetrically) further from the centre-line.

Comment: In any event, if this persists for a long time or gets worse you should probably see a doc about it.  It's helpful to know what specific syndrome is involved, and you likely can then learn some stretches/exercises from a therapist to help things.

Answer (score 3):

Foot size difference is unlikely to cause pain directly, but having an oversized shoe on the smaller foot may provide insufficient support or too much movement.  Try additional socks on the smaller foot, or an extra inner sole.

Given one foot is smaller, is it possible that leg is a bit short too?   You'd need to consult a sports physiologist, or possibly get a professional bike fit.   You can use longer bolts on your cleat, and some packing between the cleat and the shoe.

Finally, could it be a simple cleat mis-alignment?  I have recently gone clipless, and its shown me my left foot prefers a different position to my right foot.   Mind you my saddle always feels wrong unless the nose is 2-3 degrees to the left.

Comment: Hey Criggie how is your hip flexibility? My wife needed to shift the saddle to the side as well, until we tracked down  hip flexibility as the driver in her unevenness.

Comment: @rider_x Good thought - I've never checked.  I'm saving up for a new bike on my 40th, part of that will be a pro bike fit.
I've had too many broken things to be completely symmetrical :)

Comment: Most cleats are available in several float settings, meaning the angle the foot is allowed to move left or right before the mechanism releases. With Look Keo you get 0°, 4.5° or 9°. It may help finding the correct angle of the sole to the pedal axle. Speedplay pedals allow 0° to 15° float adjustment and as far as I'm informed there are plates to adjust for leg length differences.

Comment: @carel Yes very good point.  Cleat thickness could help OP as well - since one foot is smaller it could be that foot is thinner too, resulting in different stack heights per pedal.

Comment: If the difference in size of your feet is really too big you can resort to buying two pairs. You'll end up throwing out one shoe per pair but then you don't buy cycling shoes too often. Or if you buy shoes from a big company it could be possible to order a pair with different sizes. A friend of mine has to do this with riding boots.

Answer (score 2):

Most people's feet are different sizes, although in your case this may be more pronounced.

You could check that the cleats are in the same position *relative to your foot*, but I suspect the cause is elsewhere.

Check that your cleats are *straight*, and look at your pedaling action to see if your knees and feet are straight. Your knees should come close to touching the top bar as you pedal.

But the main cause of knee pain is pedaling too slowly, putting too much pressure on your knees on each pedal stroke. Since the pain is only one knee,
it's possible that you're putting too much pressure on that knee.

Usually the solution to try to pedal at a higher cadence (rate), using a lower gear. So you spin faster against less resistance. Try to pedal evenly, with the same pressure or force on each leg.

Also compare the muscle development or strength of each leg. Are they the same? Being that it's your dominant leg, I suspect not. If not, that could be something to look into. You could work to strengthen the other leg, as well as increasing your cadence.

Edit: Another thing to consider is seat height. I would expect that you would get a problem with both knees if this was the cause, but it's worth being aware of it. Generally, we get

- pain in the back of the knee when the seat is too high
- pain in front of the knee when the seat is too low.

The first results of this [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=cycling+seat+height+knee+pain) may help for this.

Comment: Knees touching the top tube is a bit of a myth introduced by CONI publication in 1972 - it was based on what the Italian Olympic committee though was an "idea" cycling form.  Same for cleat alignment, straight is a good starting position, but may or may not be appropriate depending on your biomechanics.

Comment: @Rider_X Yep, there *are* a lot of theories. I only say what I have observed in myself and others. I have seen a change to pedaling straight miraculously eliminate "chronic" knee pain almost overnight, more than once, and I've never encountered a case where pedaling straight caused a problem. Agree with your comment re cleats.

Comment: If one foot is essentially longer than the other (taking into account cleat-to-ankle distance) the seat could be too high for the shorter leg but not the longer.

Comment: @ChrisH Hmm. It's his dominant leg that hurts. I'd expect it would be longer. But a good point to consider.

Comment: @ChrisH strangely one way to handle leg length discrepancies is to use different cleat positions.

Comment: @Rider_X, that doesn't seem too surprising, the experiment could be tedious though

Comment: @ChrisH - Cycling is not a natural body movement, unfortunately tedium is sometimes  required to get a good fit (especially if you don't have "regular" problems).

Answer (score 1):

Bio-mechanics can be difficult, for your situation you may need to do some trial-and-error to get down to the root source of your pain. By switching to clip-less you lock in your foot position more than with flats, so it will likely help to compare how your position between non-clipless and clipless differs.

#### Step 1: Observe how you walk

Notice how you position your feet as you walk. This can be useful to understand whether your starting cleat position should be straight or you will need to toe-in/toe-out depending on your natural foot stance.

#### Step 2: Switch back to flat pedals and observe

Because the pain manifested after you switched to clip-less (unassumingly from flat pedals) you may need to return to flat pedals to try and track down the source of your knee pain.  Flat pedals actually have some advantages as they let you continually re-position your foot while riding which can be useful if you have some bio-mechanical peculiarity.

Ride for a while, make sure you feel comfortable, then take note of how you position your feet on the pedal.

- How is your foot positioned for/aft (i.e., the location of your metatarsals relative to the pedal axis. Current thinking is to have your the axle between the 1st and 5th metatarsal.  However, because you a foot length discrepancies one foot may need to be positioned differently in order to ensure optimal bio-mechanics for each leg (e.g., if both legs are the same length - which may or may not be the case - you will have to position your feet differently to have the same leg reach.  If you set your cleats the same position in each shoe you may have shortchanged one of your legs which could lead to pain).
- Look how your heels are you heels aligned or do they migrate in or out.  Again, depending on your bio-mechanics having straight heals or toeing your heels in or out may give you better bio-mechanics.
- Observe whether or not you change your foot position during cycling once you find a comfortable position.  If you find you need to constantly re-position your feet, clipless pedals may not give you enough range of motion to cycle comfortably.
- Finally note how far you position your feet inboard or out board on the pedal (sometimes refereed to as the q-factor)

**The goal will be try an recreate one of these  comfortable position when you set the cleats.**

#### Step 3:  Trial and error with clipless cleat positions.

After observing how you interact with flat pedals try to set up the cleats on you shoes so you get a position close as you can to a comfortable flat pedal position.  For example, you may need to move the cleat on your long foot farther back on the shoe to equalize your leg reach and provide more support for the longer foot.

Finally, you should take notice of how much float your clipless pedals have.  Different systems have different amounts and types of float (some are angular only, while others have both lateral and angular float).  Systems with more float have more tolerance for bio-mechanical imperfections.  Even within a single pedal system (e.g., SPD-SL) different cleats can change the amount of available float.

*In the end there is no easy answer.  You will likely have to employ a lot of trial and error.*

Answer (score 0):

All in all, I wouldn't recommend spending the extra money to buy different sized shoes (unless it gives you real peace of mind). From experience, just because one toe is longer than the other doesn't mean you should give up, I found that my concern about my different sized feet was unfounded.

Sports injury on a bike, usually results from over compensation of one leg/hip/lung for other, and that really depends on a number of factors. These are some that have merit, and were listed in other users answers.

- Cleat type/position is a common culprit. Moving the cleat back never hurt anyone. Not all pedals are equal.
- Saddle height is the most common reason for knee injury that I personally came across.
- Do you know if one leg is longer than the other?  However, refer to a professional when adding shims or wedges, like insoles etc.
- Socks help, I would make sure your shoes are nice and snug.

If these don't suffice get a bike fitting. Don't take my advice over that of a professionals. Check out these resources:

- [knee pain comprehensive.](http://www.stevehoggbikefitting.com/bikefit/2011/11/knee-pain/)
- [Bike fit myths](http://biker.com.au/bike-fit-myth-debunking).
- [Bike fit dynamics.](http://bikedynamics.co.uk/fit01.htm)